# Is the loss of English V to T movement connected to "do"

Tags: english, historical-linguistics

English is  unique among the European languages in that it lacks V to T movement. My professor mentioned this loss occurred in Middle English.

If I remember correctly, we also acquired the auxiliary "do" around this same time period.

Is the acquisition of "do" and *do*-support into English related to the loss of V to T movement?

Answer (score 3):

Auxiliary *do* has been around since at least the 10th century in a variety of uses, and one of those uses was the "periphrastic" (*O she doth teach the torches to burn bright*), which I take it is what you mean by "meaningless".

The restriction of S/V inversion to auxiliaries in negations and questions came much later: it was still present throughout Early Modern English and only disappeared from the 'standard' language in the 18th century; it lingered in literary use down to the 20th.

However, it strikes me as likely that the restriction would would have taken considerably longer, if it had occurred at all, if the periphrastic *do* hadn't been available to act as the 'dummy' auxiliary. The loss of periphrastic *do* is indeed pretty much contemporary with the rise of *do* support.

Comment: By meaningless I meant not semantically contentful. Is there a better term?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai "Periphrastic" is I think the usual term for the unemphatic use of *do* +tense + infinitive as an equivalent of *V* + tense. You could call it "modal" if that term weren't reserved for defective auxiliaries.

Comment: Maybe my use of "meaningless" was confusing, I was referring to *do* that is inserted in negation and questions, not literary periphrastic use. I edited it out of the question, does that make more sense?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Use of *do* as a "dummy" is usually called "do support"; "periphrastic" do, however, occurs freely in affirmative sentences down to the 18th century, and lingered in literary use. I believe it's also still alive in some British dialects. The point is that *do* was already available when inversion was restricted to auxiliaries.

Comment: I understand *do* support derives from periphrastic *do*. I'm just trying to get my terms straight. Thanks for clarifying.